# PHP: cURL ERROR: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to service.mycompany.com:443

Tags: php, web-services, wcf, soap

I have created today on my test environment (XAMP) a client consuming wcf webservice page with the nusoap library. It was working fine. Now I have send it to my customer and they have test it on production environment. The webservice is a wcf .net webservice.

They got this exception:

> wsdl error: Getting
>   https://service.mycompany.nl/SecurityService.svc?wsdl - HTTP ERROR:
>   cURL ERROR: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
>   service.mycompany.com:443  url:
>   https://service.mycompany.com:443/SecurityService.svc?wsdl
>   content_type:  http_code: 0 header_size: 0 request_size: 0 filetime:
>   -1 ssl_verify_result: 0 redirect_count: 0 total_time: 0.004144 namelookup_time: 0.001897 connect_time: 0.00416 pretransfer_time: 0
>   size_upload: 0 size_download: 0 speed_download: 0 speed_upload: 0
>   download_content_length: -1 upload_content_length: -1
>   starttransfer_time: 0 redirect_time: 0 certinfo: Array redirect_url:

This is the debug information:

> 2014-03-11 13:46:07.735808 nusoap_client: ctor wsdl=wsdl timeout=0
>   response_timeout=30 endpoint=string(54)
>   "https://service.mycompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl" 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.735897 nusoap_client: will use lazy evaluation of wsdl from
>   https://service.mycompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.735919 nusoap_client: setCredentials
>   username=webservicetestuser authtype=basic certRequest= array(0) { }
>   2014-03-11 13:46:07.735958 nusoap_client: call:
>   operation=LoginUsernamePassword, namespace=http://tempuri.org,
>   soapAction=, rpcParams=, style=rpc, use=encoded, endpointType=wsdl
>   params=array(5) {   ["Username"]=>   string(11) "test@test.com"
>   ["Password"]=>   string(10) "test!123"   ["ReturnToken"]=>
>   bool(true)   ["ReturnProfile"]=>   bool(true)   ["ReturnRoles"]=>
>   bool(true) } headers=bool(false) 2014-03-11 13:46:07.735990
>   nusoap_client: instantiating wsdl class with doc:
>   https://service.mycompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.736042 wsdl: ctor wsdl= timeout=0 response_timeout=30
>   2014-03-11 13:46:07.736062 wsdl: parse and process WSDL path=
>   2014-03-11 13:46:07.736090 wsdl: setCredentials
>   username=webservicetestuser authtype=basic certRequest= array(0) { }
>   2014-03-11 13:46:07.736111 wsdl: parse and process WSDL
>   path=https://service.mycompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.736127 wsdl: parse WSDL at
>   path=https://service.mycompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.736147 wsdl: getting WSDL http(s) URL
>   https://service.mycompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.736195 soap_transport_http: ctor
>   url=https://service.mycompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl use_curl=
>   curl_options: array(0) { } 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736223
>   soap_transport_http: parsed URL scheme = https 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.736238 soap_transport_http: parsed URL host =
>   service.mycompany.com 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736252 soap_transport_http:
>   parsed URL path = /SecurityService.svc 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736266
>   soap_transport_http: parsed URL query = wsdl 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.736289 soap_transport_http: set header Host:
>   service.mycompany.com 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736336 soap_transport_http:
>   set header User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123) 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736359
>   soap_transport_http: setCredentials username=webservicetestuser
>   authtype=basic digestRequest= array(0) { } 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736378
>   soap_transport_http: certRequest= array(0) { } 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.736402 soap_transport_http: set header Authorization: Basic
>   bWlqbnNlaF9uZXRieXRlczojbjN0Ynl0MzU= 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736423
>   soap_transport_http: set header Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   2014-03-11 13:46:07.736439 soap_transport_http: set header Connection:
>   close 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736457 soap_transport_http: entered send()
>   with data of length: 0 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736476 soap_transport_http:
>   connect connection_timeout 0, response_timeout 30, scheme https, host
>   service.mycompany.com, port 443 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736507
>   soap_transport_http: connect using cURL 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736597
>   soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=10002, value= string(58)
>   "https://service.mycompany.com:443/SecurityService.svc?wsdl"
>   2014-03-11 13:46:07.736641 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption
>   option=52, value= int(1) 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736662
>   soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=42, value= int(1) 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.736680 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=19913,
>   value= int(1) 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736700 soap_transport_http:
>   setCurlOption option=13, value= int(30) 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736718
>   soap_transport_http: set cURL SSL verify options 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.736731 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=64, value=
>   int(0) 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736749 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption
>   option=81, value= int(0) 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736768
>   soap_transport_http: set cURL username/password 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.736783 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=10005,
>   value= string(26) "webservicetestuser:webservicetestpassword"
>   2014-03-11 13:46:07.736802 soap_transport_http: set cURL for Basic
>   authentication 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736818 soap_transport_http:
>   setCurlOption option=107, value= int(1) 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736841
>   soap_transport_http: cURL connection set up 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736865
>   soap_transport_http: HTTP request: GET /SecurityService.svc?wsdl
>   HTTP/1.1 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736882 soap_transport_http: HTTP header:
>   Host: service.mycompany.com 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736898
>   soap_transport_http: HTTP header: User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
>   2014-03-11 13:46:07.736912 soap_transport_http: HTTP header:
>   Authorization: Basic bWlqbnNlaF9uZXRieXRlczojbjN0Ynl0MzU= 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.736926 soap_transport_http: HTTP header: Accept-Encoding:
>   gzip, deflate 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736939 soap_transport_http: HTTP
>   header: Connection: close 2014-03-11 13:46:07.736959
>   soap_transport_http: Skip cURL header Host: service.mycompany.com
>   2014-03-11 13:46:07.736976 soap_transport_http: Skip cURL header
>   Authorization: Basic bWlqbnNlaF9uZXRieXRlczojbjN0Ynl0MzU= 2014-03-11
>   13:46:07.736991 soap_transport_http: Skip cURL header Connection:
>   close 2014-03-11 13:46:07.737006 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption
>   option=10023, value= array(2) {   [0]=>   string(32) "User-Agent:
>   NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)"   [1]=>   string(30) "Accept-Encoding: gzip,
>   deflate" } 2014-03-11 13:46:07.737033 soap_transport_http: set cURL
>   HTTP headers 2014-03-11 13:46:07.737048 soap_transport_http: set cURL
>   payload 2014-03-11 13:46:07.737068 soap_transport_http: send and
>   receive with cURL 2014-03-11 13:46:08.384096 soap_transport_http: cURL
>   ERROR: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
>   service.mycompany.com:443 
> url:
>   https://service.mycompany.com:443/SecurityService.svc?wsdl
> content_type:
>   
> http_code: 0
> header_size: 0
> request_size: 0
> filetime:
>   -1
> ssl_verify_result: 0
> redirect_count: 0
> total_time: 0.004144
> namelookup_time: 0.001897
> connect_time: 0.00416
> pretransfer_time: 0
> size_upload: 0
> size_download: 0
> speed_download: 0
> speed_upload: 0
> download_content_length:
>   -1
> upload_content_length: -1
> starttransfer_time: 0
> redirect_time: 0
> certinfo: Array
> redirect_url: 
>   2014-03-11 13:46:08.384176 soap_transport_http: end of send()
>   2014-03-11 13:46:08.384212 wsdl: Getting
>   https://service.mycompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl - HTTP ERROR:
>   cURL ERROR: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
>   service.mycompany.com:443 
> url:
>   https://service.mycompany.com:443/SecurityService.svc?wsdl
> content_type:
>   
> http_code: 0
> header_size: 0
> request_size: 0
> filetime:
>   -1
> ssl_verify_result: 0
> redirect_count: 0
> total_time: 0.004144
> namelookup_time: 0.001897
> connect_time: 0.00416
> pretransfer_time: 0
> size_upload: 0
> size_download: 0
> speed_download: 0
> speed_upload: 0
> download_content_length:
>   -1
> upload_content_length: -1
> starttransfer_time: 0
> redirect_time: 0& lt;br>certinfo: Array
> redirect_url: 
>   2014-03-11 13:46:08.384270 nusoap_client: checkWSDL 2014-03-11
>   13:46:08.384291 nusoap_client: got wsdl error: Getting
>   https://service.mycompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl - HTTP ERROR:
>   cURL ERROR: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
>   service.mycompany.com:443 
> url:
>   https://service.mycompany.com:443/SecurityService.svc?wsdl
> content_type:
>   
> http_code: 0
> header_size: 0
> request_size: 0
> filetime:
>   -1
> ssl_verify_result: 0
> redirect_count: 0
> total_time: 0.004144
> namelookup_time: 0.001897
> connect_time: 0.00416
> pretransfer_time: 0
> size_upload: 0
> size_download: 0
> speed_download: 0
> speed_upload: 0
> download_content_length:
>   -1
> upload_content_length: -1
> starttransfer_time: 0&l t;br>redirect_time: 0
> certinfo: Array
> redirect_url:

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's a bug in Curl, because in your results you have this:

ssl_verify_result: 0

http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-bugs/07azn3bj39/43158-new-ssl-verify-result-0

Try to change your Curl version and php version (separately).